# Team Services build windows service to the deploy folder

Tags: msbuild, azure-devops

net sln witch has a website project and also a windows service project. Within team services and on my build job I am able to output the website to the drop folder using the following

/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\"

I need to also output the windows service to another folder within the drop folder

Any help would be great

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @user1488692 did you build solution directly? If so, the windows service project will be build and the files would be copied to artifact directory through Copy files task. Do you add Copy files task to copy file?

Comment: Hi. My build tasks on Team services consists of the following. 1. NuGet restore 2. Build solution with msbuild arguments: /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"  3. Publish symbols path 4. Publish Artifact: drop

Comment: In my artifacts drop folder I can see the two web sites zipped but nothing for the windows service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add Copy files task to copy files to artifact directory (Below Publish symbols path task) https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files.

For example:
[image]
The BuildConfiguration variable is in Variables tab, default is release, you may need to change to debug if you build project with debug configuration.